# How is `2` different to `[2]` when using `is`?

Tags: python

```
a = 2
b = 2
print(b is a)
a = [2]
b = [2]
print(b is a)
```

The first `print` returns `True` and the second `print` returns `False`. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python small ints are memoized to be more efficient.

So, `b is a` is `True` because they have the same location in memory.

`is` checks for object identity. If you want to check for equality use `==` except for `None` in which case there seems to be a general consensus to use `is`

```
>>> a = 2
>>> b = 2
>>> id(a)
1835382448
>>> id(b)
1835382448
```

Comment: why don't `b` and `a` have the same location in memory when both assigned to `[2]` ? aren't they pointing to the same object ? excuse my limited knowledge

Comment: *why don't b and a have the same location in memory when both assigned to `[2]` ?* This is because every time you write `[2]` you create a *new* array. You aren't reusing an existing array.

Answer (score 0):

`is` checks for object identity (is list `a` the same instance as list `b`). And `==` compares value identity (is what is stored at the variable `a` equivalent to what is stored at the variable `b`)

So in your case. `[2]` is the value, and while variable `a` and variable `b` both store the this value, they are not the same (you could modify `a`, and `b` would not change)

If you added another variable and pointed it to `a`, you could see this behavior:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = [2]
>>> b = [2]
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
False
>>> c = a
>>> c == a
True
>>> c is a
True
```